# index in c programming

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, indexing

I have a question about locating an index.

suppose I have a "relative" index in an array (that was allocated with malloc), or basically an index that doesn't tell me where I am really. how can I find the "absolute" index? 
I'm trying to use binary search to locate a number in an array but I also need the index, and when I do it with recursion I loose the actual index.

I was thinking since it is an array maybe I can subtract sized or something (suppose it's an ints array) to figure out how many steps I made from the begining but I can't quite figure it out. can you help?

Comment: What's an "absolute index"?! Is `a[0]` indexed relatively or absolutely?

Comment: After you malloc() keep the address in a safe place (and pass that value to other functions)

Comment: absolute index I mean the "distance" from the begining of the array. relative means the "distance" from some other location in the array.

Comment: how do I get the index using the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by *relative index* you mean a pointer inside the array, you can get its offset using pointer arithmetic:

```
int *array = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
// Let's say you've got a pointer to an array element somehow,
// through your recursive search or in any other way.
// I'll assign it directly for simplicity:
int *ptr = &array[23];
int absIndex = ptr - array; // This equals 23
```

The compiler deals with dividing out the `sizeof` the array element for you, so the result of the subtraction does not change if your array elements are doubles, chars, structs, or anything else. The pointer types of `ptr` and `array` need to match, though.

Comment: that's what i was thinking of doing. is it possible to do this withour a pointer? something like "absindex= &array[23]-array"?

Comment: @littlerunaway Why would you do that? You already have the "absolute" index in the `23`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's just an example of how to get that pointer. Since the OP did not give me a signature of his search function, I needed to use *some* initialization in the example.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was commenting on littlerunaway's comment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah, I see :)

Comment: about my comment, I was just using the example that dasblinkenlight used above. when I do binary search using recursion, I divide the array in half every time I enter another recursion and my array might start from a different place. so what I get in the end is just a number that doesn't really mean anything about the actual index

Comment: @littlerunaway Then yes, you can subtract `array` from `&array[someIndex]` and get the index back. The essential requirement in subtracting pointers is that they both point into the same *contiguous* block of memory, e.g. into the same array.

Comment: @littlerunaway You are welcome! If you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, consider accepting this answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it.

Comment: @littlerunaway "it's not working" isn't enough to help you any further. Please update your question with the things you tried and a description of the failure that you are getting.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. figured out the problem